# Food Truck Champion: Does the Owner card count to the 6 card hand limit?

Tags: untagged

Does the Owner card count to the 6 card hand limit in Food Truck Champion? Since I am not a mother tongue in English I don't quite understand the sentence in the rules: 'If the Owner card is in your hand, it counts towards your hand limit of 6 cards'.

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  English meaning of the quoted text is that, yes, the Owner card counts as one of the six cards you are limited to when it is in your hand. (So you can only hold five other cards)